# Controller specs in isolation mode and render :update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec, isolation

I am using RSpec for writing my controller tests/specs.

I faced the problem, that the following code gets rendered:

```
render :update do |page|
  page['middle_content'].replace_html :partial => "admin/pages/show"
end
```

Isolation mode is the default, isn't it?

How can I fix this or am I doing something wrong?

Here is for example a failing controller spec:

```
it "should be succesful" do
  xhr :delete, :destroy, :page_id => 1, :id => 1
  response.should be_success
end
```

The error message:

```
should be succesful
Mock 'Page_1' received unexpected message :title with (no args)
On line #1 of app/views/admin/pages/_administration.html.erb
```

The adminitration partial gets rendered in the show partial

Best regards

EDIT: I have posted this issue to the lighthouse account of RSpec.

Comment: could you show us an example of a failing controller test?

Comment: I have added some more code and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. If I add the following

```
controller.stub!(:render).and_return(nil)
```

everything will work(the views won't get rendered).

Does anybody of you got an idea?